# what's ssh password

Tags: ssh

[image: Rosanswers logo]

when I use ssh,it ask me provide local's password,but I don't when I set,or how can I change it

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/208277/what%27s-ssh-password/) by [cros](https://answers.ros.org/users/21043/cros/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2015-05-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2015-05-02**:
Please ask this question on more appropriate forum like some people already suggested.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Use the password for the account on the computer you're trying to log into. If you don't know, you'll need admin access to the computer so you can change the password.

---

Originally posted by [Adam Allevato](https://answers.ros.org/users/21561/adam-allevato/) with karma: 194 on 2015-05-01

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [cros](https://answers.ros.org/users/21043/cros/) on 2015-05-01**:
password of the account on the computer is useless,which is the only passwrod I know .so I don't know which is the ssh password.

**Comment by [Adam Allevato](https://answers.ros.org/users/21561/adam-allevato/) on 2015-05-01**:
We don't know anything about your system's configuration - you haven't provided us with the information.,  Regardless, this seems like a better question for StackOverflow.com.

**Comment by [cros](https://answers.ros.org/users/21043/cros/) on 2015-05-01**:
thank you all the same

Answer (score 1):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This question doesn't seem specific to ROS.  SSH (Secure Shell) is simply a way to connect from one host (computer) to another.  Presumably the host you want to connect to has a login/password you can use to gain access.  You didn't provide many details so I'll need to guess you are using Ubuntu.  When you say "local's password" it almost sounds like you are trying to login to a host with a username of 'local'.  By default it should use the username you are logged into a system as already, or can be provided a '-l' argument to provide a different username.

```
cros@hostnameA:~$ ssh hostnameB
cros@hostnameB's password: 

<your_username>@<your_hostname>:~$ ssh -l <diff_username> <another_hostname>
```

If you are new to linux,etc. I recommend starting with an introduction to SSH such as this one I randomly googled for...
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/ssh-essentials-working-with-ssh-servers-clients-and-keys

This guide for Ubuntu provides you some tutorials for basic operations of adding accounts, setting/changing passwords, etc.  if you need help with that.
https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/user-accounts.html

Best of luck.

---

Originally posted by [j12y](https://answers.ros.org/users/21634/j12y/) with karma: 51 on 2015-05-01

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [cros](https://answers.ros.org/users/21043/cros/) on 2015-05-01**:
I use the ubuntu. when I read the book ros_by_example_hydro_volume,I found there is one chapter(4.12)named networking between a robot and a desktop computer.I do follow the book,but when I do as the chapter 4.12.6 runing nodes on both machines writed:   ssh my_robot.local,the computer asked password

**Comment by [j12y](https://answers.ros.org/users/21634/j12y/) on 2015-05-02**:
Do you have two machines?  What is the hostname for each?  That example is adding a '.local' to the end of the hostname for your computers and using zeroconf to make networking easier.